# Dont show in other select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal with chips and serial codes, when I select a chip I can change the serial code, but I don't want to show the same serial code if it is selected by another select, I can't do it, can anyone help?

```js
var chipsSelecionados = [];
$("input[name='inventarios[]']").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  chipsSelecionados.push(id);
});


var optionsChips = seriais.map(function(seriais) {
  //se o selecionado
  var id = seriais.id;
  if ($.inArray(id.toString(), chipsSelecionados) === -1) {
    return "<option value='" + seriais.id + "'>" + seriais.serial + "</option>";
  }
}).join("");



$('#modal-buscar-linha').modal("hide");

var novaLinha = "<tr>" +
  "<input type='hidden' name='inventarios[]' value='" + idChip + "'>" +
  "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'><select class='form-control' style='margin: 0 auto;'>" + optionsChips + "</select></td>" +
  "<td>" + agenda + "</td>" +
  "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'><select class='form-control' style='margin: 0 auto;'><option>Não selecionar</option>" + options + "</select></td>" +
  "<td class='text-center'>" +
  "<button class='btn btn-danger delete-button' type='button'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>" +
  "</td>" +
  "</tr>";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and removed PHP/Symphony which is irrelevant to the question. Please click [edit] and update the snippet with RELEVANT RENDERED HTML and relevant frameworks from CDN

Comment: There isn't enough code / context here to offer any suggestions. Nevertheless, I wouldn't rebuild the entire DOM every time there is a change. Instead, just loop over the `select option` and toggle the `display` style based on whether or not that option is already selected.